# How to build Twitter Bootstrap 3 using Grunt

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, gruntjs

I've cloned Twitter Bootstrap 3 using git clone https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap.git:

Now, I am trying to build it using Grunt and I cannot find any documentation on how to do this.

Where should I start?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for the [Setup instructions](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap#compiling-css-and-javascript) from the project repo's README?

Answer (score 3):

To add some more automation to your project, I would suggest you is to use **[Bower](http://bower.io)**. This will even save you the time of downloading everything to your **assets**.

In order to use Bower you need **bower.json**

This file looks something like this:

```js
{
    "name": "WebExpressive",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "authors": [
        "username <username@abc.com>"
    ],
    "description": "An awesome web application",
    "license": "MIT",
    "ignore": [],
    "dependencies": {
        "bootstrap": "latest",
        "jQuery": "latest",
        "angular-latest": "latest",
        "turnjs": "latest"
    }
}
```

Now you to plug your bower to grunt you need to have a Gruntfile.js which will look something like this

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    //project configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        shell: {
            multiple: {
                command: ['bower install',
                    'mv bower_components/** public/',
                    'rm -rf bower_components'].join('&&')
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-shell');

    //Default Tasks
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['shell']);

    //production Tasks
    //grunt.registerTask('dist',[..]);

    //test tasks
};
```

Now before you actually run the **'grunt'**, make sure that you got all npm packages in your project directory and **package.json** is in correct shape.

Take a look at my **package.json** file.

```js
{
    "name": "application-name",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "grunt": "*",
        "grunt-shell": "*",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "*",
        "grunt-contrib-connect": "*",
        "grunt-contrib-coffee": "*",
        "grunt-contrib-compass": "*",
        "grunt-open": "*",
        "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "*",
        "grunt-contrib-jade": "*",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "*",
        "grunt-bower-install": "*"
    }
}
```

Now you just need to run these commands and you can find the your bootstrap inside the public folder.

```
npm install
grunt
```

Please do visit [grunt](http://gruntjs.com) and [grunt shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell/) to explore more on this, they are just great.

Comment: this seems like alot of code I would have to write to download simple css files to make a simple html css site

Comment: @TarDavis But think of the simplicity. You just give someone the `package.json` and `Gruntfile.js` and he will be able to set up everything just by running few commands. But i agree with you we spend sometime on writing `Gruntfile.js` and in beginning it looks tedious, but once the project grows it is very useful especially when a new developer joins the team he can quickly set up everything.

Answer (score 2):

For a basic instruction on how to build using Grunt you can refer to

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Essentially it's as easy as

```
grunt dist
```

If you are running from the command line in Windows, be sure to run cmd.exe as administrator.